# Could not read the excel file in server

Tags: c#, excel

Below is my code to read a excel file. This works fine in the local machine. But I move this to the server it return error.

```
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@""+Path);
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

Comment: What library are you using to read it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Comment: @JoePhillips using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: Can you include the error which is being returned, and which line of code it occurs on ?

Comment: You need to install Excel on the server but it would be better to use a decent library instead of interop

Comment: @JoePhillips Can I use plugin for this without installing the Excel to the server. Please help

Comment: @Joe please don't advise stuff that is clearly unsupported and a head f#$& of a solution

Comment: @JeremyThompson Did you skip the "it would be better" part?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because [server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) is **not** supported.

There can be so many things that can go wrong with this. Its why Microsoft has employed the XML format starting with Office 2003.

If you want to process Excel files on the server use an XML library like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) or [OLEDB](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB) as the Knowledge Base article suggests.